# Html form are stacked too close to each other

Tags: html, css

So I am making a Employee search page with HTML and CSS. It's still in the early stages, but one hurdle i'm running into is my forms are stacked pretty much right on top of each other. 
[![They are too close together ][1]][1] How can I separate them? I've tried looking on google and stack overflow but what all I've seen are just simple "first name" "last name" forms. What I thought about making a separate id for all of the them so i can adjust them accordingly but maybe there is an easier way. 
Here is my HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="Search.css" />
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Employee Search</title>
  <body>
    <main>
      <h1>
        Employee Search
      </h1>

      <form>
        <input
          type="text"
          id="fname"
          name="First Name"
          placeholder="First Name"
        />
        <input
          type="text"
          id="lname"
          name="Last Name"
          placeholder="Last Name"
        />
        <input type="text" id="ssn" name="Last 4" placeholder="Partial SSN" />
        <br />
        <input
          type="text"
          id="compID"
          name="CompanyID"
          placeholder="CompanyID"
        />
        <input type="text" id="LoginID" name="LoginId" placeholder="LoginID" />
        <input
          type="text"
          id="Dob"
          name="DOB"
          placeholder="Date of Birth as mm/dd/yy"
        />
        <input type="reset" />
        <input type="submit" value="Search" />
      </form>
    </main>
    <footer>
      <small><i>Copyright &copy; 2020 Employee Search Page</i></small>
    </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

And here is my CSS

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
h1 {
  text-align: center;
}
body {
  background-color: azure;
}
form {
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
}
input {
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: ivory;
}
footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

So to reiterate is there anything I can try to separate these? Would making separate id's work?

Comment: This is what css classes are for. May also want to familiarize yourself with the box model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a margin to the inputs themselves:

**CSS**

`form input { margin-bottom:10px; }`

Change the `px` to any amount you desire, you can also use `margin-top:10px` if looks better.

The `<br/>` does add more spacing too, or you can use a new class, for example:

**Custom classname**

```
<input class="more-spacing">

form input.more-spacing{ margin:20px 0 20px 0; }
```

Meaning `margin: left top right bottom`

**inline style tags** also work:

`<input style="margin:20px 0 0 0;">`

There are also so so many great resources out there already, absolutely worth reading as have step by step guides in most cases for example:

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_form.asp

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_margin.asp

Remember to always search first for tutorials, i promise they answer questions better than majority of stackoverflow questions you can ask, since they often have full examples of answers to questions you havent even thought to ask yourself yet :)

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful. w3schools is great, I've been using that to check syntax and just learning about other categories i plan on using. I want to eventually enlarge the textboxes and place them in center screen but the main thing i wanted is to separate them a bit, so thank you for the help.